# How to Store a PIG Bag in HBASE?

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

What I am trying to do is create nested arrays for `HBASE` within `PIG`

So basically I do the following:

```
//Loading some address data
CITY = LOAD '/user/root/landingzone/ADRPCDCITY.csv' using PigStorage(';')
AS (dPOST_CODE:chararray, dCITY_CODE:chararray);

//Create the BAG by grouping postal code
B = GROUP CITY by dPOST_CODE;

//Store it in HBASE
STORE B INTO 'hbase://TEST_ADDRESS_VALIDATION'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
       'f1: group, f1:CITY' );
```

The problem I face is that the `BAG` can not be casted to the `HBASE` Map class

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.InternalCachedBag cannot be cast to                                                    java.util.Map
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: can you provide the stack trace that belongs to the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better
i got a solution which i would like to share

```
CITY = LOAD '/user/root/landingzone/CITY_Test.csv' using PigStorage(';')
AS (POST_CODE:chararray, CITY_CODE:long, CITY_NAME:chararray);

A = FILTER CITY BY (POST_CODE) IS NOT NULL;

result = FOREACH A GENERATE POST_CODE, TOMAP(UPPER(CITY_NAME), CITY_CODE);

STORE result INTO 'CITY_ADDRESS_VALIDATION' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage( 'f1' );
```

Using TOMAP and saving it via HbaseStorage but not assigning a map there, does the trick.